# Mock canvas toDataUrl without adding another lib

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have an HTML `<canvas>` element that uses the `onTouchEnd` attribute to get the canvas content and convert to a dataUrl, but this is not supported by Jest.

Most articles suggest adding the `jest-canvas-mock` lib to mock all of the `HTMLCanvasElement` stuff. But this seems overkill as I only need to mock the toDataURL method. So I wanted to check how can I use jest.mock or jest.spyOn to mock toDataURL() and return a fixed string.

Just to make it clear, I need this because the `onChange` function sets a state value (`useState`) that controls whether a button is enabled or not.

Component.js

```
export default function MyComponent() {

  const setTouchPosition = e => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    // .. a few lines omitted for readability
  };

  const draw = e => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // .. a few lines omitted for readability
  };


  return (
    <canvas
        onTouchEnd={e => {
              onChange(e.target.toDataURL());
              onTouchMove={e => draw(e)}
              onTouchStart={e => {
                setTouchPosition(e);
              }}
            }}
        />
  );
}
```

View.js

```
export default function MyView() {

  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const onChange = image => {
    setData(image);
  };

  return (
    <Button disabled={data === ''}>Button label</Button>
  );
}
```

If the `Component.js` don't invoke the onChange function, I can't get this Button enabled and use fireEvent on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `jest.spyOn` to mock the implementation of `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL`:

I'm not sure what kind of assertions you want to run against your mock `toDataURL` method, but I assume you want to at least check that it's been called correctly.

```
const dummyDataURL = 'data:image/png;base64,<...>';
const toDataURLStub = jest
  .spyOn(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toDataURL')
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return dummyDataURL;
  });
// Create your canvas and trigger your touchend event
expect(toDataURLStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith('image/png');
```

You will probably also want to make sure you have an `afterEach` block that restores all mocks, because if your assertion fails, it will prevent the rest of the function from running (hence why I chose not to restore the stub at the end of the above code).

```
afterEach(() => {
  // This is effectively guaranteed to run even if
  // your test assertions fail
  jest.restoreAllMocks();
});
```

Comment: Using `spyOn(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL)` is causing this error: `Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: It seems that the correct syntax is `jest.spyOn(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toDataURL')`. Now I'm getting another error, but I'm still not sure if it's related to this or not.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira Ah yes, my apologies—I typo'd the function signature. I've edited my answer to correct this.

What's the new error you're getting?

Comment: The Component.js actually has some more functions that are called on the onTouchMove and onTouchStart events, and one of them uses document.getElementById to get a ref to  the canvas element and getContext from this canvas. I'll update the question to add these lines, but I think I need to mock the functions of my functional component (not sure if it's possible).